# How to Programatically perform a click event?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a HyperLink  given below,

```
<a href="www.abc.com/" id="click1" target="_blank" >Apply now</a>
```

I want to click the Link programatically on page load. can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Try with `trigger` on **page load** like

```
$(function(){
    $('#click1').trigger('click');
});
```

Or even you can use [**simulate**](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js) plugin and you can use like

```
$('#click1').simulate('click');
```

It triggers a native browser event.May be it also useful for you.

Or even simply you can try with

```
window.location.href = 'www.abc.com/';
```

Comment: +1 for possible answer (`.click()` would be shorter), but most likely OP's question is how to actually make it work to bypass browsers' restrictions on opening new windows on load/automated clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click1").click(function(){
        //your code
    });
});
```

Comment: This is sample of setting up the handler... not invoking click.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          click1.ServerClick += new EventHandler(ClearClick);
        }

     public void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }
```

This will give u the anchor tag click on page load.

```
<a runat="server" id="click1">Apply now</a>
```